# cufon H3 tag inside a block anchor not hovering

Tags: anchor, cufon

I want my headers (in the middle column) to hover white when rolled over. They are placed inside a block anchor (so everything should be an anchor). When it uses a system font (Arial  as seen on the left column) the hover works fine.

Am I approaching this fromt he wrong angle?

```
      <a class="blog-post" href="file.html">
    <img src="images/promoter-blog-image.jpg" alt="promoter blog image" width="170" height="115" />
    <h3>SMOKER? WATCH THIS AND YOU WON'T QUIT! TOM VEK</h3>
    <p class="bold">Posted by Omar on July 27, 2011 </p>
    <p>After ten years making top quality tunes, Leeds indie troop The Music play their last shows before going their separate ways at Brixton Academy.</p>
    <p>Original tickets for the show at the Shepherd's Bush Empire. are still valid.</p>
    </a> 
  <!-- /blog-post -->
```

Here is the link to the page in question.

Thanks lots,

Mitch
http://www.captivegrid.com/10Tribes-refresh/blog.html

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't work. I suggest given this context, to you to check out http://www.divydovy.com/2010/04/cufon-hover-fix/ which mentions a fix for hover of Headers inside anchors.

Also you can try

```
Cufon.replace('.overlay a', { 
  hover: true, 
  hoverables: { div: true } 
});
```

Should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The site has moved on, but still has this issue. Will look into it. Stack overflow rules.